# The order in which pipeline components are executed in shell

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

```
ls | wc
```

In which order `ls` and `wc` executed here? Or, are `|` and `wc` just arguments to `ls`?

Answer (score 4):

In the expression `ls | wc`, your shell will perform roughly the following actions:

1. start two subshells A and B, with A's standard output connected to B's standar input.
2. In subshell A, start the command `ls`
3. In subshell B, start the command `wc`
4. wait until all subshells terminated
5. set `$?` to the exit status of subshell B (i.e. the exit status of `wc`)

The `bash` manpage has more details:

> ### Pipelines
>
> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of
>   the control operators `|` or `|&`. The format for a pipeline is:
>
> ```
> [time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ [|│|&] command2 ... ]
> ```
>
> The standard output of *command* is connected via a pipe to the standard input of *command2*. This connection is performed before any redirections
>   specified by the command (see `REDIRECTION` below). If `|&` is used, the
>   standard error of command is connected to *command2*'s standard input
>   through the pipe; it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`. This implicit
>   redirection of the standard error is performed after any redirections
>   specified by the command.
>
> The return status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last
>   command, unless the `pipefail` option is enabled. If `pipefail` is
>   enabled, the pipeline's return status is the value of the last
>   (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all
>   commands exit successfully. If the reserved word `!` precedes a
>   pipeline, the exit status of that pipeline is the logical negation of
>   the exit status as described above. The shell waits for all commands
>   in the pipeline to terminate before returning a value.
>
> If the `time` reserved word precedes a pipeline, the elapsed as well as
>   user and system time consumed by its execution are reported when the
>   pipeline terminates. The `-p` option changes the output format to that
>   specified by POSIX. The `TIMEFORMAT` variable may be set to a format
>   string that specifies how the timing information should be displayed;
>   see the description of `TIMEFORMAT` under Shell Variables below.
>
> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in
>   a subshell).

Answer (score 0):

No,ls not handle the pipe argument,this done by shell.

The content of stdout of ls command was, taken as input of wc from stdin.

**ls *[stdout]*|* [stdin]* wc -l**

the command wc will get that stdout content as input.

Here both commands are executed as different process by shell. 
which means both have different PID.

For Verify youself this answer,use **ps|cat.** you can see that different process cat and ps.

```
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
11695 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
12207 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
12208 pts/1    00:00:00 cat
```